# RadGrid Ajax PopAlert

Tags: jquery, ajax, telerik

I have a situation where I need to, based on user selection and some server-side processing, display a message to allow 
user to choose to continue processing or cancel. I have a RadGrid populated with data from the database. When User adds a new item to the grid,I want to do some processing in the back end and then inform the user of what could result and give him/her the choice to continue and believe that a message box or modal popup/radalert is the best way to do it, but how do I create the message in the back end and then using a popup, display the message and block until user responds. How do I do it please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create the confirmation dialog inside the ItemCommand or InsertCommand event. Here is an thread with [example code](http://www.telerik.com/ClientsFiles/135008_confirmfromserver-aspx.zip) about [Opening Rad confirmation Pop up from the server side](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/opening-rad-confirmation-pop-up-from-the-server-side.aspx)

See also:
[Adding a delete confirmation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grdaddingdeleteprompt.html)